# phonegap/ Cordova error: [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to create a phonegap / cordova app using the 3.1.0 version.
Created my app with the command:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

And after running this command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

to add android platform, i am getting:

```
[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
```

Any idea what could be the issue?, previously i created another app, but same error was occurring when adding camera plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue, but I was actually issuing the command in wrong directory, so firstly I changed the directory to **Hello** then issued the command.

So, I have directory structure as, 
  ---Cordova
      ---Hello

and I was actually issuing the command by being at Cordova folder. After that I changed the folder to **Hello** then executed this **cordova platform add android** and it worked.

Please check once

Comment: Thanks Ankur, nice detail

Answer (score 1):

be sure you are located in the created directory (Hello, I guess), the same level with .cordova

```
cd Hello
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yup i am on the Hello directory... but same issue

Comment: do ls (linux) or tree (dos) to know more info

Comment: You were right Khaled, i was actually wrong, i created the project, manually and was trying to add Android platform. when a retry it , it worked smoothly. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this question after July 2013 (when Cordova 3.0.0 was released), there is another reason for this problem.

If you created a Cordova project on a computer with Cordova 3.x and you are trying to work with it on a computer that still has the old 2.x version, you will get this error because of how the project structure changed between the versions.

Upgrading Cordova to the newest version using `npm install -g cordova` will fix the problem.